# How can I rework my forms to prevent such erroneous data being passed into my database?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my database, There are some improperly formatted data. for example

```
1. ap@trigroup.net;;anand@gmail.com;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
2. judihard@aol.com;;williamdeloney@gmail.com
3. ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

My challenge is to show in proper format in HTML form. for example

```
1. ap@trigroup.net;anand@gmail.com
2. judihard@aol.com;williamdeloney@gmail.com
3.
```

I try to use javascript replace method but that does not work for me. How can I then replace a portion of the value using JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: Perhaps a better question would be: "How can I rework my forms to prevent such erroneus data being passed into my database?". Can you say "Pre-Submission Form Validation"?

Comment: ok @gavgrif. let me update. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to split string by `;` and remove empty entry

```
var newArray = data.split(';').filter(function(v){return v!==''});
```